# Insert data in ADF table cell by cell

Tags: oracle-adf

I am working on ADF application. 
I have table and I need to insert data into it cell by cell and column by column in order.

For example:

[image: ADF table]

- on start, all cells should be disables except only one cell (the first cell at YearworkDegree column)
- if user entered value for that cell it should open below cell.. etc
- after finishing YearWorkDegree column it should open first cell from the second column MidtermDegree and so on.

Is there a feature in ADF I can use in that case, or should I think in JavaScript to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the properties of one field to be dependent on the other and set partial page refresh between the two - so when you change the value in the first - the second on becomes enabled.

That being said - doing this is going to cause  a lot of chattiness to the backend server (on each field change).

Answer (score 1):

So you basically need something like tab navigation between cells but in a different order (downwards). There is no integrated functionality for this in ADF, you have to do it by yourself by writing a custom JS handler.
Please check [this example](https://technology.amis.nl/2016/03/15/navigating-adf-editable-table-arrow-keys/)

You can then modify it for your needs (making only the current cell enabled for editing, etc).